# How to change Tabbar iconcls corresponding Tabbar item selected in sencha touch

Tags: css, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have done application using sencha touch2. in tab-bar i want to show to user, **once iselect the item from tab-bar then need to change normal image to selected image.** Right now i am doing via sass styles.Normal images are coming fine,but when i select/activate item. it is not changing normal icon to selected-icon. i gone some articles i have applied it is not working for me. below i have given code. can any one tell me how to achieve this one.

**View page code:**

```
config: {
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
items: [{      
        iconCls: 'ApartmentIcon',
        autoDestroy:true,
        layout:{
            type:'vbox',
            pack:'center'
        },
        scrollable: true,       
        fullscreen:true,
            items: [
                     {
                      //Some items
                     }
                  ]
       }
   ]
}
```

**Css code: i gone below four ways,but once i select image is not changing.**

```
.ApartmentIcon{
  @include image-tabIcon('data:image/png;base64,NormalimageBase64code....=',70px,90px);
}

ApartmentIcon.x-button-pressing{
  @include image-tabIcon('data:image/png;base64,SelectedimageBase64code....=',70px,90px);
}
.ApartmentIcon.x-tab-active{
  @include image-tabIcon('data:image/png;base64,SelectedimageBase64code....=',70px,90px);
}
.ApartmentIcon.selected{
  @include image-tabIcon('data:image/png;base64,SelectedimageBase64code....=',70px,90px);
}
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab-active:first-child{
  @include image-tabIcon('data:image/png;base64,SelectedimageBase64code....=',70px,90px);
}
```

Comment: Can you try .x-tab-active .ApartmentIcon {...}

Comment: x-tab-active .ApartmentIcon {@include image-tabIcon('data:image/png;base64,SelectedimageBase64code....=',70px,90px);}

Comment: @TDeBailleul..I have tried as u told.it is not working. cay any one tell me how to do this one.